# Find non server control attribute value in postback?

Tags: asp.net

I can get the value of non server control with Request.Form["fieldID"];

how i can get the attributes of these control?
some think like these :
 Request.Form["fieldID"].Attribute["the_Attribute"].value;

or any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to get the fieldId because its value is included in the POST, its attributes however will not be.

I'd recommend using something like firebug or fiddler to see the info that's coming in on the request, or even using the locals or immediate window to explore the Request.Form object to get a feel for what you can/can't do in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are no attributes. The only thing sent in the form data to the server is the value from the form field.